# How do I deal without ByRef in an Async function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, task

I'm working on replacing my old code that uses threads to a .NET 4.5 Task based system.

I have the following sub that I wish to convert;

```
Public Function Delay(Milliseconds As Integer, ByRef Job As Job) As Boolean
   For i As Integer = 1 To CInt(Milliseconds / 100)
      Thread.Sleep(100)
      If Job.IsCancelled Then Return True
   Next
   Return False
End Function
```

The Job class is one of my own, but importantly it contains an integer which is set to 1 if the job should be cancelled.  So, the Delay function allows me to put a thread to sleep for X milliseconds, but if the job is cancelled during that time it will stop sleeping and return True.

I'm not sure how to do this with Await Task.Delay, here's my attempt;

```
  Public Async Function Delay(Milliseconds As Integer, Job As Job) As Tasks.Task(Of Boolean)
    For i As Integer = 1 To CInt(Milliseconds / 100)
      Await Tasks.Task.Delay(100)
      If Job.IsCancelled Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
  End Function
```

The problem I'm having is that Async methods don't allow me to use ByRef, which means it won't be able to detect when the Job has been cancelled.  Another issue is that await can't be used inside try/catch/finally or a synclock.  I was under the impression you can write asynchronous code that looks like synchronous code.  How can I get around these issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not actually mutating the `Job` variable in the body of your method, so you shouldn't be passing it by reference at all, you should be passing it by value.

That is, unless `Job` is actually a mutable value type instead of a reference type, in which case *that* is your problem and you should fix it by not using a mutable value type here.

It's also worth noting that if you wish to use an object to encapsulate the possible cancellation of an asynchronous operation you should use `CancellationToken` (and the accompanying `CancellationTokenSource`).  It will provide all of the functionality that you need, and of particular note, it will handle all of the proper synchronization such that you won't run into any problems accessing it from multiple threads.  It also happens to be a reference type.

If you accept a `CancellationToken` you'll also be able to pass it to `Task.Delay`, allowing it to complete when the token is cancelled, rather than forcing your method to wait until the delay is over to `return false`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding the CancellationToken.  I edited by question just after you answered but I'm also having trouble using the new function in my old code. I can't use it in synclock sections.  Is there a way to deal with that?

Comment: @iguanaman That's an entirely separate question from what you are currently asking.  You should ask a new question about it.  You should also be including the specific code that you are using, as that's very relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to declare `Job` as a `Class`, and not a `Structure`.  This will allow it to be passed `ByVal` (the default) and work perfectly in your code as described, as it will be a reference type and mutations handled externally will be visible within your method.

Since you don't change `Job` inside of your function, it shouldn't be passed `ByRef`.